# Acumatica - how to return the last modified date for SalesInvoice?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to filter `Acumatica SalesInvoices` by last modified date but I'm not seeing a Last-Modified field when getting SalesInvoices via the `API`. I have been able to successfully filter other entities by last modified, I'm only having issues with `SalesInvoices`.

The last modified date is returned with other entities such as Contacts, Customers, SalesOrders, etc. but it is not included in the response for SalesInvoice (shown below):

```
ex: GET
.../entity/default/18.200.001/SalesInvoice/


"id": "f56c816c-d56a-ea11-8177-b7035bd537d0",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": "",
    "Amount": {
        "value": 1064.9700
    },
    "Balance": {
        "value": 1064.9700
    },
    "CashDiscount": {
        "value": 0.0000
    },
    "CreditHold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Currency": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "C000001"
    },
    "CustomerOrder": {},
    "Date": {
        "value": "2020-03-20T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    "Description": {},
    "DueDate": {
        "value": "2020-04-19T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    "Hold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Project": {
        "value": "X"
    },
    "ReferenceNbr": {
        "value": "0000002"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Balanced"
    },
    "Type": {
        "value": "Invoice"
    },
    "custom": {},
    "files": []
```

How can i return the last modified date on the SalesInvoice entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 2019R1 environment, the endpoint for **SalesInvoice** does not include out-of-the-box the **LastModifiedDatetime** field.

[image: ++++]

Whereas **Customer** - for instance - does include it:

[image: +++++]

You should extend the endpoint and include the field explicitly like this:

[image: ++++++]

(note that LastModifiedDateTime will not be available in the dropdown of the Mapped field column. You should type it in directly)

Then you should use the new endpoint name to retrieve that information:
[image]